# Excel VBA: Saving several sheets in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to save a list of worksheets in a new workbook.
This worked well:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("a1", "a2")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="myFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

However, the list of worksheets is always different so I produced a string variable `Pgs` with the text in the brackets `"a1", "a2"` in this case.

So it looked like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(Pgs)).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="myFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Did not work. I tried different options with adding and removing quotation marks form the beginning and end ect. I found topics where referring to one page from string variable is discussed but never several pages like in my case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is sound, but the problem is this:

```
Array(Pgs)
```

Will create a single index array that looks like this:

```
Array[0] = "a1", "a2"
```

So unless your sheet is named `"a1", "a2"`, this will not work.

However, this should work:

```
Pgs = "a1,a2"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Split(Pgs, ",")).Copy
```

Because the `Split` function will return an array broken apart by a comma. In this case `Split(Pgs)` would have an array like:

- Array[0] = a1
- Array[1] = a2

Comment: I made a couple of modifications but in general did like you wrote. Perfect!